# Argument list too long: /bin/sh on Linux redhat

Tags: linux, shell-script, rhel, compiler

I am having a script named as test.sh, which I use to run as below, which works fine:-

```
/root/test.sh
```

Then i tried to compile this script using the shc compiler as below with Warning:-

```
shc -v -r -T -f test.sh
shc: WARNING!!
Scripts of length near to (or higher than) the current System limit on
"maximum size of arguments to EXEC", could comprise its binary execution.
In the current System the call sysconf(_SC_ARG_MAX) returns -1 bytes
and your script "test.sh" is 155201 bytes length.
shc shll=sh
shc [-i]=-c
shc [-x]=exec '%s' "$@"
shc [-l]=
shc opts=
shc: cc  test.sh.x.c -o test.sh.x
shc: strip test.sh.x
shc: chmod go-r test.sh.x
```

as a result of this warning i am not able to run this compiled file:-

```
./test.sh.x
./test.sh.x: Argument list too long: /bin/sh
```

How can i increase the limit of _SC_ARG_MAX so that i can compile the scripts.

Comment: As you can see: 1) It's a warning, not an error, and 2) the value -1 for the current `_SC_ARG_MAX` is nonsensical. Also 3) You would have to change the limit in one of the system header files and recompile everything that uses that header.

Comment: The -1 thing I alluded to above means no matter what you increase `_SC_ARG_MAX` to, it would likely still complain as it doesn't seem to read the value correctly.

Comment: `sysconf(3)` returns -1 only in case of an error.  `_SC_ARG_MAX` is required by POSIX, so you're looking at a bug either in `shc` or in your `libc`.

Answer (score 1):

The program that you are using is not reading `_SC_ARG_MAX` correctly and reports it as `-1`.

This means that even if you tried to increase this value (which would include fiddling in the system header files and recompiling at least the kernel and a few utilities), it would probably *still* not read the correct value.

The message is a warning, which means that it's not fatal. It is likely that whatever operation the utility preformed went ok.

The system configuration variable `ARG_MAX` (which has the value of the symbolic constant `_SC_ARG_MAX`) has the value 2097152 on Ubuntu and 262144 on OpenBSD (`getconf ARG_MAX`). Your value, 155201, is well within those.

I don't have access to a RedHat machine to see what this value may be there.

Comment: I am on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6

Current Value in **limit.h** is as below:-
`#define ARG_MAX       131072    /* # bytes of args + environ for exec() */`

Comment: My project works fine in linux with a smaller arg_max but fails in openbsd.